# Why is my Nexus 6 not being detected by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Nexus 6 I am trying to use for debugging an Android app. I have USB debugging turned on on the device and Windows 8.1 seems to recognize it correctly. However, whenever I try to debug the application in Android Studio, the device never shows up under the 'Choose a running device' list in the 'Choose Device' modal. Has anyone else encountered this issue while debugging android apps on this device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install google usb driver
download it in android SDK and you need to install it manually